# How to force a Swift iOS app only in portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am writing an iOS app in Swift and I would like to prevent the user from using the app in landscape mode. Is there a way to easily block any view to portrait mode only?

Comment: Sure, it's totally up to you whether the user can rotate to landscape or not.

Comment: Go to you project settings and scroll down to "Device Orientation," then just check "Portrait" only

Answer (score 1):

Just go to you app setting -> Deployment Info -> Device Orientation, and tick on "Portrait" only

Comment: When running my app on a simulator the layout still rotates to landscape. I have only the "Portrait" checkbox selected in Deployment Info and it doesn't seem to occur on physical devices, do the simulators ignore this property?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do the following

1. Click on the icon of your app: [image: app]
2. You should get this: [image: this]

Then you set only portrait mode